# install minimal desktop on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, gnome, desktop, desktop-environment

I just want to install a minimal GNOME desktop without all the Thunderbird/Firefox and any other packages that may come with full CentOS Live Cd. Is there something like `yum groupinstall base-desktop`? Ideally, I just want Xorg/GNOME and then add any other packages manually. No `gdm` also, I just want to run `startx`.

Answer (score 4):

There's the `basic-desktop` group which is described as

> A minimal desktop that can also be used as a thin client.

It includes the following packages:

- at-spi
- control-center
- control-center-extra
- dbus
- eog
- gdm
- gdm-plugin-fingerprint
- gdm-user-switch-applet
- gnome-applets
- gnome-media
- gnome-packagekit
- gnome-panel
- gnome-power-manager
- gnome-screensaver
- gnome-session
- gnome-terminal
- gnome-vfs2-smb
- gok
- gvfs-archive
- gvfs-fuse
- gvfs-smb
- metacity
- nautilus
- NetworkManager
- NetworkManager-gnome
- notification-daemon
- openssh-askpass
- orca
- polkit-gnome
- pulseaudio-module-gconf
- pulseaudio-module-x11
- rhn-setup-gnome
- vino
- xdg-user-dirs-gtk
- yelp

It includes gdm which is arguably part of a basic desktop but does not include Firefox, Thunderbird, etc. If you still want less, you'll want to pick the packages out of the above list you want and do a yum install on the specific ones you for your desired desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Centos will install Gnome as default Gui.

```
# yum groupinstall basic-desktop desktop-platform x11 fonts
```

or

```
# yum groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

To install KDE

```
# yum groupinstall "KDE desktop"
```

from http://namhuy.net/475/how-to-install-gui-to-centos-minimal.html

Answer (score 2):

The stuff you are talking about won't amount to much on disk, maybe 1/2 GB or so at most.  If your space is so that tight this is a concern, then you will need to find a minimal install sans X and build up from there.  If you want to end up with anything involving GNOME at all though, this probably won't make much difference, and it is a hassle.

That said, I notice this remark [here](http://www.centos.org/) under "CentOS 6 Releases":

> There is also a minimal install CD that will get you a very small base
>   install that you can add to.

With regard to booting to console and using startx, this is just a matter of setting the default runlevel.  CentOS still uses a SysV style init system.  Look in `/etc/inittab` for this line:

```
 id:5:initdefault:
```

There are probably some comments that go with it.  Change the 5 to a 3 and you will no longer boot straight into X.

Installing gnome without gdm will be impossible, but that does not mean you have to use it.  `startx` will obey the directives in `~/.Xclients` if it exists (it does not by default).  Try creating this file and saving it in your $HOME as `.Xclients`:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-session
```

Comment: Yes, CentOS still uses sysvinit-style setup. As things look right now, RHEL 7 will use systemd, but that is just a guess on my side.

Comment: @vonbrand : cheers, I edited the "maybe" parts out ;)